# Error when importing tensorflow (with virtualenv) on MacOS

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip, virtualenv

I've been struggling with getting tensorflow to work. Not sure what the problem is. I believe I have the latest version of pip, python, tensorflow, and protobuf (which seems to cause similar problems for others) installed.

To get to the error message I do:

```
$ cd targetdirectory
$ source myenv/bin/activate
(myenv)$ python3
>>> import tensorflow
```

This is my error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/dannyguy/targetDirectory/myenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
  File "/Users/dannyguy/targetDirectory/myenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "/Users/dannyguy/targetDirectory/myenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "/Users/dannyguy/targetDirectory/myenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 114
    def TFE_ContextOptionsSetAsync(arg1, async):
                                             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I had this error message before. Not really sure why there's a different one now.

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: try pip free see if you have already installed it successful

Comment: pip 10.0.01 is installed under python 3.7, so I don't think that's the problem.

Comment: Sorry guy, I mean did you check your tensor is installed by use “pip freeze”

Comment: Downgrade to Python 3.6.

Comment: FRANK AK - This is what shows up:
        $ pip freeze
        protobuf==3.6.0
        six==1.11.0
Does this mean tensor was not installed under python?

Comment: Thanks Gurmeet Singh! That was the solution as tensorflow doesn't seem to support 3.7.

Comment: The word `async` became a reserved keyword in Python 3.7. The code is for Python 3 <= 3.6.